# impresión directa desde jspdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf, imprimir

estoy generando un comprobante con jsPDF, no tengo dificultades en ello, y una vez generado abro un diálogo de guardar o abrir ... esto me permite guardar el pdf generado localmente o abrirlo en una pestaña nueva del navegador y a partir de allí (ambos casos) mandar a imprimir el pdf.

Pero necesito saltarme ese proceso de abrir el pdf o guardarlo y en vez de eso, enviarlo directamente (el pdf generado) a la ventana diálogo de impresión.

El método que estoy usando es ...save('nombre.pdf') quiero saber si hay alguna opción similar pero que se oriente a imprimir directamente y no a guardar el documento.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto:

```
<script>
function creaComprobante() {
    var opciones = {
        orientation: 'p',
        unit: 'mm',
        format: [240, 300]
    };

    var doc = new jsPDF(opciones);

    doc.setFontSize(10);
    doc.text(10, 30, 'Recibo de venta de orquídeas');
    doc.text(10, 35, 'Comprobante No.: 7854214587');
    doc.text(10, 40, 'PDV: Pedro Pérez');
    doc.text(10, 45, 'Operador: 123654');
    doc.text(10, 55, 'Especie vendida: Sophronitis coccinea');
    doc.text(10, 60, 'Valor: 35.00');
    doc.text(10, 65, 'TBX: 242985290');
    doc.text(10, 70, 'Fecha/Hora: 2019-11-05 12:28:21');
    doc.text(10, 90, '_______________________________');
    doc.text(10, 95, 'Recibí conforme');


    doc.autoPrint({variant: 'non-conform'});

    doc.save('comprobante.pdf');
}
</script>
```

Comment: una consulta, te imprimio directamente??? porque a mi me sigue abriendo el dialogo

Comment: Si, se imprime perfectamente, tener en cuenta la respuesta bajo estas líneas, donde explico lo que hice

Answer (score 0):

Ya he resuelto ... sólo he cambiado las dos últimas lineas de la función:

```
    doc.autoPrint();

    doc.output('dataurlnewwindow', {filename: 'comprobante.pdf'});
```